# If $x+y\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ is a root of $f$ then $x-y\sqrt{n}$ is also a root

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ be a non-square integer and  $x+y\sqrt{n} \in \mathbb{C}$ a root of $f\in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ with $x,y\in \mathbb{Q}$. Show that $x-y\sqrt{n}$ is also a root of $f$.

To show this, I want to construct a homomorphism from $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that fixes the field $\mathbb{Q}$ and sends $i\mapsto -i$ and $\sqrt{n}\mapsto -\sqrt{n}$. So it also takes roots of $f$ in $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{n})$ to roots in $\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{n})$. Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't do this by constructing a homomorphism. Write $f$ as $ax^2+bx+c$, and see what it means for $x+y\sqrt{n}$ to be a root of $f$ (and please avoid calling two different things $x$).

Comment: @darijgrinberg: You can't (immediately) assume $f$ is a quadratic since it is not given to be the minimal polynomial.

Comment: @user21820: Oops, you're right.

Comment: @darijgrinberg: However your way can be easily finished as I show in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your approach is right. However, you can construct a homomorphism on $\def\qq{\mathbb{Q}}$$\qq(\sqrt{n})$ that fixes $\qq$ and maps $\sqrt{n}$ to $-\sqrt{n}$. You need to prove that it works, but then after that you are more or less done since homomorphism fixes polynomials over $\qq$.

The other way is as Darij said in a comment, namely that if $n$ is not a perfect square then $\qq(\sqrt{n})$ is a non-trivial extension of $\qq$ and hence has degree at least $2$. But you can indeed find a quadratic $g$ over $\qq$ with roots $x \pm y \sqrt{n}$. If $g \nmid f$, then you can get a contradiction because you get a linear polynomial over $\qq$ with root $x+y\sqrt{n}$.